# Uninstall FOSHttpCacheBundle

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I installed FOSHttpCacheBundle and decided to try to remove it afterwards.

- I ran the `composer remove` (my `composer.json` does not contain the FOSHttp line anymore)
- I removed the line in the `AppKernel.php`
- I removed the corresponding lines in `config.yml`

Yet now, in production mode, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FOS\HttpCacheBundle\EventListener\CacheControlSubscriber' not found in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php on line 145

It stacks up from the bootstrap.php file which I rebuilt using `composer install`.

Should I re-install FOSHttpCacheBundle?

Comment: Maybe you have some services to remove, or annotations in controllers as well.

Comment: I did not annote any controller. I removed the call to the Bundle in AppCache. And I don't have this error in dev mode.

Comment: I get the error when clearing the cache. I will manually clear it now.

Comment: Manually clearing it did the trick. Thanks!